# Is this result about conditional expectation well known?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose $x$ is a random variable while $y$ is a number. Let
\begin{equation*}
D(y)=\mathbb{E} \max\left\{x,y\right\}-\max\left\{\mathbb{E}x, y\right\},
\end{equation*} which can be interpreted as the "benefit" of unfolding $x$. The result is
\begin{equation*}
argmax_{y} D(y)=Ex
\end{equation*}
My proof is as follows.

Let
$C(y)=\mathbb{E} \max\left\{x,y\right\}=yF(y)+\int_y^{+\infty} xf(x)dx$.
$\frac{\partial C}{\partial y}=F(y)+yf(y)-yf(y)=F(y)$.
So if $y<Ex$, then $\frac{\partial D}{\partial y}=F(y)\geqslant 0$. If $y>Ex$, then $\frac{\partial D}{\partial y}=F(y)-1\leqslant 0$.

I was wondering whether this is a well-known result and what the related results/insights are.

Comment: I do not understand the main equation.  Can you give an example, such as $X \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ and $y=2$?  I would have thought this gives $\mathbb{E} \max\left\{X,y\right\}=2+e^{-2}\approx 2.1353$ while $\max\left\{\mathbb{E}X, y\right\}=2$ and $\mathbb{E}X=1$ .  What is $\arg\!\max_y\mathbb{E} \max\left\{X,y\right\}$?

Comment: @Henry Sorry for the confusion. The maximization is with respect to two terms rather than the first term. I edited the question hoping to clarify it.

Comment: Are you saying the value of $y$ which maximises $D(y)=\mathbb{E} \max\left\{X,y\right\} - \max\left\{\mathbb{E}X, y\right\}$ is $\hat y= \mathbb{E}X$ and gives $D(\hat y)=\mathbb{E} \max\left\{X, \mathbb{E}X\right\} -  \mathbb{E}X$?

Comment: @Henry Exactly.

Comment: Thank you - with your edit to the question, it is clearer now